# Insert Identity Column Value into Row Being Inserted LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to integrate two systems together, the old system has a database that is not normalised in the slightest.

What I'm trying to do is insert a row into the old database that requires the identity columns value.

So for example:

```
(Auto Incremented PK) RECNUM = 648
GST_INVOICE = 648
```

I need to insert 648 into GST_INVOICE when the row is created.

Sorry don't know the best way to explain it.

EDIT: Using LINQ to insert the new data.

Comment: Why `LINQ` here? Unless you explain more about your problem, for example this is not related to `server` that means all the rows are in-memory.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry. I'm using C# LINQ to insert the data.

Comment: why WPF here?  There doesn't seem to be any UI component